# How to generate image from html in react js or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, google-chrome

I am developing a page in react js in which I need to generate the image from the Html code which is rendered using drag n drop HTML content like text.

I have tried to use a dom-to-image package but it gives me the image of the container's actual size like if the container size is 500 x 500 then it will give me the image of the size 500 x 500. If I mention height and width there then it gives me a cropped image of that size.

I need the image in different sizes with a similar view of the content.
But right now I am getting either a large image or a cropped image.
Is there any other library or another way by which I can get the same image in different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is bit late. but if someone is still seeking an answer, you can use html-to-image react plugin.

```
/* ES6 */
import htmlToImage from 'html-to-image';
/* ES5 */
var htmlToImage = require('html-to-image');

var node = document.getElementById('my-node');
 
htmlToImage.toPng(node)
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
```

Comment: I'm using this package, but for some reason I'm getting some extra transparent space on the right side of my exported image. There is nothing in the html. Any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

"html-to-image"
this package show me this message:
"Attempted import error: 'html-to-image' does not contain a default export (imported as 'htmlToImage')"